# Is there a way to see the list of pending S3 Glacier retrievals in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I've initiated the retrieval of an S3 file using the *Glacier Deep Archive* storage class, using the AWS console. I just got a success message, and no link to a page where I can monitor the status of my retrievals.

**Is there a way to see the list of pending retrieval jobs, together with their status, on the AWS console?**

If not, I'd accept an AWS CLI command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [s3 restore-object CLI documentation page](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/restore-object.html).

> To get the status of object restoration, you can send a HEAD request.
> (...) You can use Amazon S3
> event notifications to notify you when a restore is initiated or
> completed. For more information, see [Configuring Amazon S3 Event
> Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)s in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

When it says "head" I assume it's referring to [S3API Head](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html). That would be:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket --key index.html
```

*Note that this is using AWS CLI v2, if you're using V1 the syntax may be a bit different.*

While the archive is being retrieved, the JSON will contain a `Restore` key similar to:

```
"Restore": "ongoing-request=\"true\""
```

When the archive is ready to be downloaded, the `Restore` key will change to something like:

```
"Restore": "ongoing-request=\"false\", expiry-date=\"Thu, 17 Sep 2020 00:00:00 GMT\""
```

You can then proceed with downloading the archive from the AWS S3 web console like any other file.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see the `x-amz-restore` header in the output: https://pastebin.com/bYEWsKet

Comment: Are you calling it on the source object or the object being restored? It'd be worth trying it on both, or checking the docs to see what it suggests. From memory the docs were a bit vague.

Comment: I’m calling it on the source object. How do I know the key of the object being restored?

Comment: Not sure sorry, I've never tried it. Maybe someone else who has done this can help more.

Comment: Not sure if the docs are up to date; they might actually mean `HEAD` as an HTTP verb, as I've not been able to locate the `x-amz-restore` header. However, I got the answer to my question, in the form of the `Restore` key in the JSON output, and updated your answer accordingly. Hope you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah good move adding more info :)